# SUMIFS with Date Range...but X days before and X days after

Tags: excel, function, sumifs

I am trying to create a SUMIFS function that is adding totals based on several parameters.  The final parameter is to use a date in a column and then look for any dates 7 days prior and 7 days after.

I have a list of invoices I am trying to sum up based on travel...conceivably people who are traveling will travel in a short duration.  I cant add all invoices up because someone might travel at the beginning of the month and at the end, creating 2 trips.

Lets say the date is in Column I and my criteria cell is I10, I tried to enter the Criteria Range as "(I10-7)=>I10<=(I10+7)"

But this is clearly wrong.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The 'final parameter' needs to be two pairs of parameters; one pair for >=date-7 and one pair for <=date+7.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=sumifs(A:A, I:I, ">="&I10-7, I:I, "<="&I10+7)
```

Add your other criteria pairs making sure that the criteria ranges are the same number of rows as the sum range.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!  How would you cram this into an index and match array function?  I have created this array: =INDEX(Sheet2!$I:$I,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!$F:$F=D4)*(Sheet2!$D:$D=J4),0)) where the second part is looking for the date (J4 is the date, Sheet2!$D:$D has the dates).  However there is not an exact match...the date in J4 could be a week in advance or behind on Sheet2!$D:$D.  Can we cram your function into this to make it return values?  Thank you so much btw!!!